# target ie 8 and lower to convert 'x-img src' back to 'img src'

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer

I am using mobify.js for my responsive images. However, I have to add 'x' before my img src so it reads 'x-img src'. This works on all browsers apart from ie 8 and below.

So my question is, is there a way using javascript to change the 'x-img src' tag back to the normal 'img src' tag in ie?

Answer (score 0):

```
//sets the image source equal to the x-src
element.setAttribute('src',element.getAttribute('x-src'));
//removes x-src
element.removeAttribute('x-src');
```

Comment: Sorry the tag was actually 'img x-src' not 'x-img src'. I tried your solution but still not working in ie 8 and below.

Comment: <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class = "item active">
        <img x-src = "images/vh1.jpg" alt="Vinehouse Homepage">
       </div>

Comment: Okay, thinking out of the box here would it be a bad idea to have both 'x-src' and 'src' for IE fallback? It seems that mobify.js would get the proper image & the fallback would be in place for IE.